# Why is the Stable-Baselines3 evaluate_policy() function never finishing/completing?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, stable-baselines, openai-api

I have created my own custom environment using OpenAI Gym and Stable-Baselines3. Once I've trained the agent, I try to evaluate the policy using the evaluate_policy() function from stable_baselines3.common.evaluation. However, the script runs indefinitely and never finishes.

As it never finishes, I have been trying to debug the 'done' variable within my CustomEnv() environment, to make sure that the environment **always** ends one way or another. Other than that I am at a complete loss.

The code that I am using is below (for brevity it doesn't include the environment code):

```
env = CustomEnv()
env = Monitor(env, log_dir)
model = PPO("MlpPolicy", env, verbose=1, tensorboard_log = log_dir)

timesteps = 5000
for i in range(3):
  model.learn(total_timesteps = timesteps, reset_num_timesteps = False, tb_log_name = "PPO")
  model.save(f"{models_dir}/car_model_{timesteps * i}")

mean_reward, std_reward = evaluate_policy(model, env, n_eval_episodes=1)
```

Any suggestions or advice on how to debug this would be amazing.

Comment: Hi Alex, did you find a solution to this? I'm stuck in the same situation, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem few days ago. From my situation, the reason that my 'evaluation helper' never stop is : My custom environment did not have timesteps limit per episode. Thus my evaluation function was running forever (because my policy at is good and agent did not fail).

Comment: Is it possible to configure `evaluate_policy` function to limit the number of timesteps instead of episodes?

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons `evaluate_policy` may not stop:

1. The episode never ends - `step()` never returns `done=True`.
2. `done` is ignored by the `evaluate_policy` because the environment is wrapped into a `Monitor` wrapper and the wrapper can't detect termination     correctly.

For the first case, check if your environment with all its wrappers still returns `done=True` (also called `terminated` in some implementations) in the `step()` method at some point.

About the second case. When you use the `stable_baselines3.common.monitor.Monitor` wrapper, `evaluate_policy` [ignores](https://github.com/DLR-RM/stable-baselines3/blob/master/stable_baselines3/common/evaluation.py#L109) the `done` variable and checks for "episode" key instead that [is set by](https://github.com/DLR-RM/stable-baselines3/blob/v1.8.0/stable_baselines3/common/monitor.py#L110) the `Monitor` wrapper. It is set either when the environment is 'done' or when it is 'truncated', which happens when a special wrapper like `gym.wrappers.TimeLimit` terminates the environment [before it returns](https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/v0.21.0/gym/wrappers/time_limit.py#L22) `done=True`. In this case, the `TimeLimit` wrapper is responsible for returning the `done` information.

The order of the `Monitor` and `TimeLimit` wrapper matters. `Monitor` should go after `TimeLimit` for the evaluation to detect time truncation:

```
env = MyEnv()
env = gym.wrappers.TimeLimit(env, max_episode_steps=max_episode_len)
env = Monitor(env, allow_early_resets=True)
```

The logic is the following. TimeLimit truncates MyEnv before it returns `done=True`, but returns its own 'done' to indicate the truncation. Monitor gets 'done' from the TimeLimit, sets the 'episode' key and also returns 'done'. `evaluate_policy` checks that MyEnv is wrapped into a Monitor, ignores the 'done' information and checks for 'episode' key instead. The key is there so the episode is considered finished by the `evaluate_policy`.

If instead Monitor and TimeLimit were the other way around, Monitor would not get the `done=True` since MyEnv would still be truncated by the TimeLimit wrapper, but after the Monitor has already performed its check. So no 'episode' key would be set and the environment would be reset, but the `evaluate_policy` would not detect that is has finished.

Depending on the version, TimeLimit may also provide information about the truncation in some way like `info["TimeLimit.truncated"] = not done`, but it is not used by the `evaluate_policy` method directly.